# Passing props down to component which are not children

Tags: components, react-props, siblings

I have to systematize some knowledge.

How can I pass props

```
ParentComponent
   -Child1Component
   -Child2Component 
        -Child2.1.Component
             -Child2.1.1.Component
                 -Child2.1.1.a.Component
   -Child3Component
   -Child4Component
```

**First issue**

How can I pass props from Child3Component to Child4Component ?

1. form Child3 -to- Parent & from Parent -to- Child4 ?
2. using context
3. what else?

What is the bast way to pass props through components which are not connected ?

**Second issue**

How can I pass prop from Child2Component to Child2.1.1.a.Component so that the intermediate components don’t use that single prop.

I was trying to understand Composition on reactjs.org but I need clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Redux and useContext are the ways you can pass the state to non connected components.

When you are building a small scale application then you can go with useContext. But when you are going to build any large scale application than go for redux. Because redux helps you to keep your code organised and helps to test the code easily.

But never try prop drilling. It is ok if u pass the props by max 2 levels.